# JUnit test case for Camel route for ActiveMQ

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, junit5

I have a camel route in `MyRouteBuilder.java` file which is consuming messages from ActiveMQ:

```
from("activemq:queue:myQueue" )
.process(consumeDroppedMessage)
.log(">>> I am here");
```

I wrote a test case for the following like this :

```java
@Override
public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new MyRouteBuilder();
}

@Test
void testMyTest() throws Exception {
    String queueInputMessage = "My Msg";
    template.sendBody("activemq:queue:myQueue", queueInputMessage);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

}
```

When I run the unit test case I get this strange error:

```
7:53:26.175 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Route: route1 >>> Route[activemq://queue:null -> null]
17:53:26.175 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Starting consumer (order: 1000) on route: route1
17:53:26.175 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer - Build consumer: Consumer[activemq://queue:null]
17:53:26.185 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer - Init consumer: Consumer[activemq://queue:null]
17:53:26.185 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer - Starting consumer: Consumer[activemq://queue:null]
17:53:26.213 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3fffff43[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
17:53:26.215 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Reconnect was triggered but transport is not started yet. Wait for start to connect the transport.
17:53:26.334 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Started unconnected
17:53:26.334 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Waking up reconnect task
17:53:26.335 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - urlList connectionList:[tcp://localhost:61616], from: [tcp://localhost:61616]
17:53:26.339 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Established shared JMS Connection
17:53:26.340 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Resumed paused task: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker@58c34bb3
17:53:26.372 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Attempting 0th connect to: tcp://localhost:61616
17:53:28.393 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport - Connect fail to: tcp://localhost:61616, reason: {}
```

I am especially stumped to see these messages:

```
Route: route1 >>> Route[activemq://queue:null -> null]
```

and

```
urlList connectionList:[tcp://localhost:61616], from: [tcp://localhost:61616]
```

Why is the queue coming up as `null` though I have a proper queue name? Also why is the broker url `tcp://localhost:61616`?

I want to run this unit test case so that it runs properly in all environments like: local,  DIT , SIT, PROD etc. So, for that I cannot afford the broker url to be: `tcp://localhost:61616`.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here and what I should be doing?

**EDIT 1:**
One of the issues that I am seeing is even before the test class is called, the `MyRouteBuilder()` inside `createRouteBuilder()` is invoked, leading to the issues that I see in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting up an explicit active mq broker , I started using a VM broker .

```
@Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
                ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
                activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
                context.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent);
                from("activemq:queue:myQueue").to("mock:collector");
            }
        };
    }
```

Also , I mistook camel junit as a traditional junit . We don't need to call explicitly the actual route builder class . Instead after setting up my activeMq component up above , I was able to write my test methods, mock my end points for queue and send messages and assert them . Camel is truly versatile . Requires a lot of study though .

Comment: Note: You should look to replace ActiveMQComponent with JMSComponent. The ActiveMQComponent is deprecated in ActiveMQ 5.16.x and removed in upcoming 5.17.x

Answer (score 1):

The "activemq:queue:.." is telling Camel to use the auto-configure magic behind the scenes (which uses default url) and your use case is beyond that.

You need to configure a connection factory (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) and configure a camel-jms component to use that connection factory.

The connection factory allows you to specify url, userName, password, default connection settings and setup SSL.

A best practice is to externalize the url, userName, password and queue to a properties file so you can change those across the environments-- local, DIT, SIT and prod, etc.

NOTE: Use org.apache.camel/camel-jms component, and not the org.apache.activemq/activemq-camel component. activemq-camel is deprecated and being removed in ActiveMQ 5.17.x.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Are there any live examples that you know of to help me out . I am scouring the internet for a long time , but not finding the appropriate use case for me .

Comment: upvoted for mentioning the activemq component .